# How can I put comma between multiples authors ,title,publisher ,year etc in bibliography in Latex?

Tags: latex, bibliography, overleaf

For example, i used "ieert" style,but this bibliography style puts comma between publisher,year,but after title puts dot

I would like a bibliography like this:
[1] S. C. Chapra and R. P. Canale,Numerical methods for engineers, vol. 1221, Mcgraw-hill New York, 2011.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows us how you create your bibliography

Comment: I created simple    \bibliography{references.bib},references.bib include the bibliography like this @book{numerical,
  title={Numerical methods for engineers},
  author={Chapra, Steven C. and Canale, Raymond P.},
  volume={1221},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Mcgraw-hill New York}
}     and i used \bibliographystyle{ieetr} like i said...sorry i'm a begginer to latex,i learn..

Comment: and i want comma between every element of the bibliography:title,authors,publisher,year etc

Comment: Please make a [mre], a small but compilable test document which allows us to reproduce the problem. Edit your question and add it there. As you can see, comments without code formatting are not suited to share code because linebreaks etc, are lost.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.